# How to build an application with the watchOS 2 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

In the last submission of our application, we have received this warning :

***Invalid WatchKit Support*** - Starting April 1, 2018, all apps submitted to the App Store for Apple Watch must be built with the watchOS 2 SDK or later

My question is to know how to to build the application with the watchOS 2 SDK?

I was thinking that is enough to build with XCODE 9.

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Deployment Target. It's likely it wasn't updated just by using a newer version of Xcode.

[image]

Also try checking Base SDK in Build Settings of your Watch Extension to make sure it is up to date.