# How to convert an apple watch app into native

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos

Apple recently annunced "Starting April 1, 2018 updates to watchOS apps submitted to the App Store must be native and built with the watchOS 2 SDK or later."

I've an app with its associated watch app, developed with watchOS 1.

How should I "convert" an apple watch app into an apple watch "native app"?

Also, in order to use watchOS 2 should I only set 2 as minimum target?

Thanks

Comment: Same topic: [How to build an application with the watchOS 2 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49174059/4667835)

Comment: NOT the same topic: I'm asking for the part "must be native" not for the version requirement.

Comment: It is actually. There never was a way to write non-native watchOS apps. The only new requirement is to target watchOS 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if this is true Apple is messaging a non-sense sentence to all developers. I still have the doubt that when I will submit the app I can have issues. Why specify 2 requirements if 1 of these is not?

Comment: It is a true requirement, it is just not a change in requirements, but rather  an emphasis on an existing one.

Comment: I dont think you are correct David. 

WatchOS 1 ran on the iPhone and projected a screen image to the watch. WatchOS 2 apps are native, running on the watch hardware.