# iTunes store operation failed. WatchKit error while uploading build on TestFlight from Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, build, watchkit, apple-watch

Invalid WatchKit Support - All apps submitted to App store for Apple Watch must be built with the watch OS 2 or later. This the error which i am receiving from Apple. I am using Xcode 9.3.
[I have checked base SDK in all targets also which is mentioned in given link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174059/how-to-build-an-application-with-the-watchos-2-sdk)
I also tried recreating Watch App Target and extension also but no success.
Please check screen shot also of error. There is a missing icon warning which i understand but this red error is a big headache for me.

[image]

If anyone has uploaded a build with watch after April 1, 2018 any help will be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Comment: What targets are in your project for the watch?  Apple no longer supports submitting a watchOS 1 target.

Comment: I have changed the target to latest 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, there might be problem with target OS.

1. Remove all WatchOS 1 targets and files
2. Add new WatchOS 2 or later targets

Clean and build and then try upload.